ATmega328p Memory Addresses
I learning to program the ATmega328p microcontroller in C and Assembler:

In C, I define DDRB = 0x24.
In Assembler, I define DDRB = 0x04

Can someone explain this difference in addresses (does that because the definition of the general purpose registers r0..r31, 0x00 .. 0x1F) ??

SFRs can be accessed memory mapped or i/o mapped. You may very well use DDRB = 0x24 in assembly as well if you then use memory access instructions instead of i/o.

This is an AVR address mapping thing not related to C vs assembler.

This is because the I/O address space is also mapped in the memory address space. It allows C to access them without using special instructions like OUT and IN.
You can use the 0x24 in assembly too - using the load and store instructions
It is not related to the language you use.
I strongly advise you to read the AVR documentation.


can i know the title of the AVR documentation please?

it is called datasheet

I downloaded the ATmega328p datasheet, but I can't find this page and the information about memory mapping
